# Перестал работать куки после закрытия всплывающего окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookie

Перестал работать скрипт, контролирующий появление всплывающего окна, после закрытия, при нажатии на крестик и фон

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close-btn,#background_popup").click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 100));
    $.cookie("popup,bg_popup", "", {
      expires: date
    });
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").hide();
  });

  $("#m-p-yet-reg").click(function() {
    $.cookie("popup,bg_popup", "1", {
      expires: 1
    });
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").hide();
  });

  if ($.cookie("popup,bg_popup") == null) {
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").show();
  } else {
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#bg_popup {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  border: 0px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display:none;*/
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#background_popup {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup {
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 999;
  /*  position:fixed;
        margin:0 30%  auto;
        z-index: 9999999;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        background: transparent;
        display:block;*/
}

.close {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
  color: #ccc;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bg_popup">

  <div id="background_popup">
  </div>

  <div id="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#" title="Закрыть" id="close-btn">X</a>

    <div id="main-pop">
      <center>
        <div class="main-pop-head">
          <img src="img/main-pop-head.png" alt="">
          <p class="m-p-h-text-1">Подпишись на нас</p>
          <p class="m-p-h-text-2">Получи 15 страниц нашего платного продукта<br>Эпоха Мудрости за быструю подписку на наш блог</p>
        </div>
        <form action="">
          <input type="email" id="m-p-email" class="main-pop-input-field" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="">
          <label for="m-p-email" class="m-p-label-email"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>это поле обязательно для заполнения</label>
          <input type="text" class="main-pop-input-field" placeholder="Ваш город">
          <button class="m-p-get-gift">Получить в дар</button>
          <div class="checks">
            <input id="m-p-check-1" type="checkbox" name="agreement" checked hidden required="" />
            <label for="m-p-check-1"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>Я даю свое согласие на обработку персональных данных и соглашаюсь с условиями и политикой конфиденциальности.
         </label>
            <input id="m-p-check-2" type="checkbox" name="agreement" checked hidden required="" />
            <label for="m-p-check-2"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>Я хочу получать email-письма о мероприятиях  и/или иных услугах
         </label>
          </div>
        </form>
        <form action=>
          <button id="m-p-yet-reg">Я уже зарегистрирован</button>
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли браузера присутствуют?

Comment: все заработало, когда я через локал хост запустил страницу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог запуск страницы через localhost